# How to show that $\int_{C_R} \frac{e^{i\alpha z }}{z^2+1}dz \to 0$ as $R\to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $C_R$ is a semicircle centered at $0$ with radius $R>0$. How can we show that the integral $\int_{C_R} \frac{e^{i\alpha z }}{z^2+1}dz$ tends to zero as $R\to \infty$?

My idea is to estimate the bound of the integrand, but it seems that it only works when $\alpha \ge 0$.

It is clear that $\left| \frac{{1}}{z^2+1} \right|\le  \frac{{1}}{R^2-1}$. Then we want to show that $|e^{i\alpha z}| = |e^{-\alpha y}|\le 1$ for $y>0$.

What is the difference between the two parametric representations, $Re^{it}$ and $Re^{-it}$ ($0\le t\le \pi$)? Note that $\alpha$ can be either positive or **negative**.

Comment: if $z=x+iy$ then $|e^{i\alpha z}|=|e^{i\alpha x}\cdot e^{-\alpha y}|=\frac{1}{e^{\alpha y}}$

Comment: @rtybase I saw that, but the issue is that $\alpha$ can be negative and $e^{-\alpha y}>1$ for $y>0$ in this case.

Comment: Indeed it can, so you can't rely on $|e^{i\alpha z}| \leq 1$.

Comment: just divide the problem into two cases according to the sign of $\alpha$ and use the corresponding, appropriate half circles. Then, you should be able to get a single answer by using $|\alpha|.$In fact, it should be $\dfrac{\pi}{e^{|\alpha|}}$

Comment: @dezdichado Could you explain how do different half circles affect the evaluation of the bound?

Comment: @user398843 like, if $\alpha>0$, then use the parametrization: $Re^{it}$, so as to have: $e^{i\alpha z} = e^{i\alpha Re^{it}} = e^{i\alpha R\cos t}e^{-R\sin t}.$

Comment: @dezdichado Thank you. It works!